# Convert a string to a byte string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert a string to a byte string. The string comes exactly in this form. 'сp1251' encoding. How to do it right?

```
str = 'см³' 
bytes(str, 'cp1251')
```

As a result, I get

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xb3' in
>   position 2: character maps to < undefined >

Comment: I can not rewrite the string in this form см ^ 3. Comes line with superscript.

Comment: Looking at code page 1251 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251, there isn't character `³`. How do you want to encode it?

Comment: You can convert it using `'utf-8'` encoding.

Comment: arsho, thanks for the reply. When you write to the file use utf-8 it turns out  'РјВі'

Comment: Andrej Kesely,  thanks for the reply. Do not tell me what encoding should be used then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the string `s` in text mode, unicode string handling is already standardized in Python3 and it's done automatically (32-bit Unicode to utf-8 conversion is automatically performed from memory (variable `s`) to file:

```
s = 'см³'

# with text-mode:

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(s)

print(open('file.txt', 'r').read())
```

Prints:

```
см³
```

If you want to be specific, you can read/write from/to file using binary mode `b` flag:

```
# with binary-mode:

with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(s.encode('utf-8'))

print(open('file.txt', 'rb').read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Prints:

```
см³
```